# Character Encoding Problem with ReadList

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I have a .srt file (subtitle file) with the following text:

> Chapitre 1 : Systèmes d'équations linéaires et matrices

However when I import it into Mathematica, using:

```
subRip = ReadList[subRibFile, String];
```

I get:

> Chapitre 1 : SystÃ¨mes d'Ã©quations linÃ©aires et matrices

**How can I avoid that ?**

Comment: What do you get if you do `Import[ subRibFile, "Text"]`?

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks for your comment. In that case, I get one string which is not seperated by lines... but the output is correctly decoded. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a workaround, using "import" but it works !

```
subRipIm = Import[subRibFile, "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
subRip = DeleteCases[StringSplit[ToString[subRipIm], "\n"], ""];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  This works ! :)